# Sharepoint workflow task time limite

Tags: sharepoint-2010, workflow

I am building share point workflow 
I want 
one of the tasks to be end after time 
IE : if the user did not approve this task in 30 minutes the task is end
and the next task start 
is there a possibility for some thing like this in share point workflow 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these posts:

- http://amarkeev.wordpress.com/2011/11/11/item-expiration-reminders-in-sharepoint-using-workflow/
- http://thingsivefoundout.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/triggering-workflow-when-expiry-date-is.html

Try to use add minutes in the date and store date, check stored date time with current time.